# Using pydub on AWS lambda

Tags: python, lambda, ffmpeg, pydub

Ok, so I have the same problem as here: [Using pydub and AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61667628/using-pydub-and-aws-lambda) but thought it would be cleaner to re-ask here as I have made some progress (I think?).

I followed the instructions here: https://medium.com/faun/how-to-use-aws-lambda-layers-f4fe6624aff1 like this:

1. I created a lambda_function.py file:

```
from python.pydub import AudioSegment

print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)

    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/audio.mp3")

    etc...
```

Using docker, I created the dependencies with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PKG_DIR="python"

rm -rf ${PKG_DIR} && mkdir -p ${PKG_DIR}

docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/foo -w /foo lambci/lambda:build-python3.6 \
    pip install -r requirements.txt --no-deps -t ${PKG_DIR}
```

and the requirements.txt file:

```
pydub
ffmpeg
```

Docker downloaded 4 folders:

```
ffmpeg
ffmpeg-1.4.dist-info
pydub
pydub-0.24.1.dist-info
```

and I uploaded the whole project to lambda as a zip file.

When I run the code I get an error:

```
/var/task/pydub/utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
```

I'm guessing that I need an ffmpeg binary uploading to Lambda but I'm not sure, and if I do, not sure how to do it.

What steps am I missing?

UPDATE:

So I've modified my code and also ran the code using pycharm.  Although ffmpeg and ffprobe are uploaded to my lambda function, and I have programmatically confirmed they are present, they fail to run.

My code is now like this:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    l = logging.getLogger("pydub.converter")
    l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

    AudioSegment.converter='/var/task/ffmpeg'
    
    print(event)

    print("00000")
    print (os.getcwd())
    print("00000")
    
    print ("1111")
    path = "/var/task"
    dir_list = os.listdir(path)
    print (dir_list)
    print ("1111")

    print ("11111111111111111")
    out = check_output(['/var/task/ffprobe', 'test.mp3'])
    print (out)
    print ("11111111111111111")
```

and this is the cloudwatch error log:

```
00000
/var/task
00000
1111
['.DS_Store', 'ffmpeg', 'get_layer_packages.sh', 'lambda_function.py', 'lambda_function.py.orig.py', 'python', 'requirements.txt', 'test.mp3']
1111
11111111111111111

[Errno 8] Exec format error: '/var/task/ffmpeg': OSError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 32, in lambda_handler
    out = check_output(['/var/task/ffmpeg', 'test.mp3'])
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 423, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/var/task/ffmpeg'
```

Any ideas?  I have made ffmpeg and ffprobe executable using chmod +x

Could this be a lambda permissions issue somehow?

Comment: thank you for taking an acceptance :))

Answer (score 2):

To use `pydub` library and many others sound playing libraries you have to install the `ffmpeg.exe` to the same directory. You can download that executable from here https://ffmpeg.org/

Comment: ok, I added ffmpeg executable (ffmpeg-4.3-i686-static from here: https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and the ffmpeg error has gone.  However, I now have an ffprobe error and adding ffprobe to my project root (with chmod +x) hasn't helped.   Any ideas?

Comment: Update: so there seems to be a problem with ffprobe and python 3.8?  I've moved to 2.7 and now don't get the ffmpeg/ffprobe complaints.  However, I have new issues, posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905735/no-such-file-error-using-pydub-on-osx-with-pycharm

Comment: @MichaelHarrison as the FFmpeg error is gone can you accept my question and upvote it, please?

Comment: @MichaelHarrison can you accept it, please? Click the second button below the downvote, please :)

Comment: I think it deserves to be an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

If useful I want to show a workaround that allowed me to have pydub (with ffmpeg and ffprobe) correctly working on my AWS Lambda function.
Please note this solution is not elegant.

1. Create a new folder called 'python' in your local machine.
2. Install the pydub library in the created folder with this command (bacuse usually your local machine is Windows but the machine running the Lambda function is Linux): `pip install pydub --target C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\python --only-binary=:all: --upgrade --platform manylinux2014_x86_64`
3. Go to the python/pydub/utils.py file and change the `get_encoder_name` function with simply:

```py
def get_encoder_name():
    return "/opt/python/ffmpeg"
```

4. Go to the python/pydub/utils.py file and change the get_prober_name function with simply:

```py
def get_prober_name():
    return "/opt/python/ffprobe"
```

5. Go to this website https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ and click on ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz to download the static builds.
6. Unzip ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz. Inside you will find the files ffmpeg and ffprobe. Move this two files inside the python folder you just created.
7. The final python folder should contain a folder called "pydub", another folder called "pydub-0.25.1.dist-info", and two files ffmpeg and ffprobe.
8. Zip the python folder and use it for the lambda layer

I also don't like this solution but it is the only way I found to let pydub work on my Lambda function (which I also put here as a reference):

```py
import json
import boto3
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    print("Initialize S3 client")

    # Get bucket name and file key from the Lambda event
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    source_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    print(f"source_bucket: {source_bucket}")
    print(f"key: {source_key}")
    
    original_file_name = source_key.split('/')[-1].replace('.mp3', '')
    print(f"original_file_name: {original_file_name}")
    
    # Temporary location for downloading the file
    download_path = f'/tmp/{original_file_name}.mp3'
    upload_path = f'/tmp/cut-{original_file_name}.mp3'
    print(f"download_path: {download_path}")
    
    # Download the MP3 from S3 to Lambda's ephemeral storage
    s3.download_file(source_bucket, source_key, download_path)
    print("Downloaded mp3 file from S3")
    
    # Fetch the metadata from the object
    response = s3.head_object(Bucket=source_bucket, Key=source_key)
    cut_times_str = response['Metadata'].get('cut-times', '')
    print(f"cut_times_str: {cut_times_str}")
    
    # Parse the cut_times_str into a list of tuples (start_time, end_time)
    cut_times = parse_cut_times(cut_times_str)
    print(f"cut_times: {cut_times}")
    
    # Load the MP3 file
    audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(download_path)
    print(f"Audio mp3 loaded")
    
    # Cut the audio according to the specified times
    cut_audio = cut_audio_segments(audio, cut_times)
    print(f"Audio mp3 cut")
    
    # Export the cut audio to a file
    cut_audio.export(upload_path, format="mp3")
    print(f"New audio mp3 generated")
    
    # Define the output bucket
    output_bucket = MY_OUTPUT_BUCKET
    
    # Upload the cut MP3 to the output S3 bucket
    s3.upload_file(upload_path, output_bucket, source_key)
    print(f"Uploaded cut mp3 file to output S3 bucket")
    
    # Delete the original MP3 file from the input S3 bucket
    s3.delete_object(Bucket=source_bucket, Key=source_key)
    print(f"Removed original mp3 file from input S3 bucket")
    
    os.remove(download_path)
    os.remove(upload_path)
    print("Deleted downloaded mp3 file in the temp local folder")
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Successfully processed and uploaded MP3.')
    }



def parse_cut_times(cut_times_str):
    """Parse the cut times string into a list of (start, end) tuples."""
    times_list = []
    for part in cut_times_str.split(','):
        start, end = map(int, part.split('-'))
        times_list.append((start, end))
    return times_list



def cut_audio_segments(audio, cut_times):
    """Cut the audio based on the specified times and return the combined audio."""
    combined = AudioSegment.empty()
    for start, end in cut_times:
        segment = audio[start:end]
        combined += segment
    return combined
```